# svn:ignore for a file already committed in subclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

I am trying to ignore some files that I have already committed to the repository in subclipse

I followed this from [Subclipse svn:ignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066809/subclipse-svnignore)

> You can't svn:ignore a file that is
>   already commited to repository.
>
> So you must:
>
> 1. Delete it from the repository
> 2. Recreate it in Eclipse
> 3. Set svn:ignore on it via Team->Add to svn:ignore

I am still getting a greyed out menu when I select Team->Add to svn:ignore

1. I deleted the folder I don't want from the repository
2. I reverted the project Team->Revert (this is the bit I may have done wrong)
3. selected Team->Add to svn:ignore but it is greyed out.

what do I need to do?

Comment: I'd say instead of reverting, you need to *commit* the change.

Comment: but I deleted the files from the repository not eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to Update from svn, rather than reverting, to pull in the changes that you made in the repository.

Revert in Subversion just re-syncs your working copy with the server, at the version you had previously checked out. If you made the change elsewhere, you need to update your working copy to point to the *newer* version on the server: that's the update operation.

Comment: Do you know what this is called in subclipse?  Nothing like 'Update from svn' is found in the menu.

Comment: According to the page at http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-ecl-subversion/, there should be a "Team > Update" option.

Comment: Got it, 'Team->Switch to another Branch/Tag/Revision' then select the trunk.

Comment: Actually there is an item that says 'Update to Head' maybe that does the same thing