# What files should I ignore in an Android Project on SVN

Tags: android, svn

I have added the 'gen' folder to svn:ignore, are there any others I should be ignoring?

***Update:***

There are some I am unsure about

```
.classpath
.project
The .settings folder
```

And also, to ignore a folder I am just typing **gen** into the ignore list in subclipse, is this correct?  How would it know if gen is a folder or file?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Just ignore gen and bin directories.

Comment: would I be correct in simply adding the words 'bin' and 'gen' on different lines in subclipse?  Do I need any slashes?  I can't find any information on this online!

Comment: Not sure I don't use subclipse. Maybe this can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066809/subclipse-svnignore/1069412#1069412

Comment: looks like this is the case, just a single name on each line

Comment: As an aside for those using Eclipse with Subversive, install the optional **JDT Ignore Extensions**. If you've already installed Subversive w/o these, just go to `Help >> Install New Software`. Pick `Indigo` or your version from the `Work With` choices, and then type **JDT Ignore** for the filter text and install. Now you can just right click on the folders to ignore (`bin` and `gen`) and pick `add to svn:ignore`.

Comment: I think `local.properties` should also be ignored.

Answer (score 6):

Not quite.
If you want to easily import and export the project just make sure that all file in the **gen** and **bin** folders and exclude, but keep the folder themselves this will help import the project. if you don't do it, you will have ot make them yourself every time you import the project.
but you should also exclude:
.classpath
.project
The .settings folder

***Summary you need to exclude:***
**.classpath**
**.project**
**The .settings folder**
**the content of bin **
**the content of gen **

Note:
If you want to import the project you need to import from existing code - you don't have the project file so it is not a project you import... Just to remembered.

Answer (score 2):

I see no answer has been given on the question about ignoring folders. The best way to go is `/*folderName`. If you want to keep the folder but ignore contents as Mashiah suggested, that would be `/*folderName/*`

For example, to ignore the contents of the `gen` folder:

`*/gen/*`

Answer (score 0):

Probably the R.java and other files generated from your .aidl interfaces (if they are already not in your 'gen' directory

Comment: yeah, R.java is inside the gen folder