# Eclipse: excluding jar files from Subversion

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

I have created a new project within MyEclipse and scafolded a Spring framework.

When I Team Share to Subversion using Subclipse it is uploading all the .jar files, not just my code. With Spring that means a lot of overhead.

I cant find a way from within the ->Team Share dialogue to exclude .jar files.

This is the first time this has happend - other Subclipse projects seem to have behaved as I hope.

How do you set the settings to exclude .jar? And how can I make that the default behaviour for future projects?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a thing about Eclipse or how it interacts with subversion, but with the subversion client installed on your path, the the typical way to ignore files is to use the propset command.

```
svn propset svn:ignore *.jar
```

[SVN Manual - svn:ignore](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch07s02.html)

Answer (score 0):

This should answer you question: [Subclipse svn:ignore](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1066809/256544)

You should add the "Wildcard extension" `*.jar` to the svn:ignore properties.