# Subversive: how to add to svn ignore

Tags: eclipse, subversive

I am using Subversive and I have the same question as [Subclipse svn:ignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066809/subclipse-svnignore), but the solution did not work for me. Anyone knows how to add to svn:ignore files already added to a project with Sobversive?

If I delete it and create it again, there is a red exaclamation ('!') icon and I am not able to add it to svn:ignore

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must delete the file and **commit** the deletion. Then you can re-add the file, and put it under svn:ignore.

Comment: Ok, I had some conflicting problems, I marked as merged conflicting files in the repositoy view, I updated, and finally I could delete and commit the deletion.