# Linked src folders in Eclipse project and SVN issue

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse, src, project-setup

I have an eclipse project set up that is NOT directly placed inside an SVN checkout tree - instead I use 'link src' option in eclipse to set up my project. Thoughts went behind this approach are primarily geared towards keeping the SVN checkout tree free from all the clutter that Eclipse (and any running plugins) would make when creating a project directly pointing to a parent svn tree structure. The problem I have with this approach is that subclipse is failing to read-in .svn info from 'linked src' folders therefore features such as compare / history are not available for any of these linked resources. Question is is there a work around? If not is there a better approach?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use svn ignore to keep the clutter away from your svn tree? See [Subclipse svn:ignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066809/subclipse-svnignore)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Gorkem. Agree, it is an attractive alternative. However say; you use a plugin that adds more hidden files to the project directory (or others)... then this approach would become tedious manual process..wouldn't it. 

As far as linked src folders are concerned - Eclipse does pick up .svn info as long as project root is inside a versioned folder..however if the project root does not point to a versioned dir then it does not.. :(

Comment: +1 You can define a list of resources along with regular expression patterns. You don't need to it for all files one by one.  eg. /target/*  anything inside target folder will be ignored.

Comment: I have noticed that myself. It is useful and that's what we are doing. One must do that manually anyway..let's if there is a new developer joining the team, this info must be somewhere there on the wiki telling them not to check-in these changes..it is this kind of issues I am trying to eliminate.

Answer (score 1):

Subclipse follows the strategy for being "link friendly" in the Eclipse documentation, which namely means that we automatically ignore linked resources.  See:

http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/team_resources_linked.htm

Subclipse relies on Subversion API for all operations and Subversion works with the file system.  It has no knowledge of Eclipse-specific functionality like linked resources, so it can only follow the normal semantics of a Subversion working copy.  It could never see the existence of these resources as part of a working copy.

Subclipse requires the project root is a working copy and then whatever else is included or ignored is based on the Subversion features you use.

Comment: so we have no solutions to this problem in this particular configuration of tools :(

anyway, thanks to you all for the replies.