# How to Remove a Folder From Committing in SVN (Eclipse)

Tags: eclipse, svn, version-control, subclipse, springloops

I know I might get slammed for this question, but I have looked at previous SO questions and have not found my answer.

I am using SpringLoops to host my SVN version control. I am using **Subclipse** an SVN plugin for Eclipse.

When I right click my project's root folder and do `Team -> Commit` I do **not** want to include the `bin` folder to that committ. Yes, I have previously committed it, and according to this question: [Subclipse svn:ignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066809/subclipse-svnignore) I have to delete it from my repository first. I am not sure what this exactly means. I cannot delete from the Springloops website, and inside Eclipse when I delete the `bin` folder it just is automatically recreated (of course).

How can I remove the `bin` folder from my commits?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I figured this out. I am an idiot. To save people future headaches, you need to go to the `SVN Repository` view in Eclipse (the top right hand corner by default, where it says `Java`, `Debug` etc. Delete it from THERE, then "update to head" and then you can right click and add to `SVN:ignore`. Then, this change should be committed.

Comment: First of all, thank you because this solved the same problem I was running into. Second: just a small clarification. The Eclipse _perspective_ from which the activity starts is `SVN Repository Exploring` . Then the resources are updated to head revision by right clicking, selecting `Team --> Update to Revision... ` from the context menu and then choosing `Head Revision` from the "Revision" radio buttons.

Answer (score 1):

In you self answer, your are not really deleting the file/folder. In SVN, you have to commit the deletion. Depending on what version of SVN, Eclipse, SVNKit etc. you have it might be tricky or buggy via the GUI though.

Comment: So, is the last step to commit? And then my answer is ok? Feel free to correct me.

Comment: Yes. If the only change you have is that you deleted a file, that will show up in your next commit as a deletion. If it's a folder and it's not empty, my experience is that it's the best to first empty it and commit those deletions in one step, and then delete and commit the deletion of the folder in an other step - the avoid problems/bugs in eclipse/SVN.

Comment: Thanks, I just did it all in one go before I read your comment and it seemed to work *fingers crossed*